# How do I install OpenAFS on Fedora 24?

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-24

I asked a question yesterday about AFS and Fedora, and from the answer given to that question I now understand why following the guide I was following online did not work.

I have now started again and am attempting to install OpenAFS on a Fedora 24 system.

I am reading this page of the installation manual: http://docs.openafs.org/QuickStartUnix/HDRWQ143.html

I obtained the packages:

> openafs, openafs-server, openafs-client and openafs-krb5 packages, along with an kmod-openafs package

by doing the following:

- https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/jsbillings/openafs/
- Quick Enable: `dnf copr enable jsbillings/openafs`
- `dnf update`
- `dnf install openafs openafs-server openafs-client openafs-krb5 kmod-openafs`

That seems to have worked...

I am now confused by the following lines in the installation guide:

> You can find the version of your current kernel by running
>
> ```
> # uname -r
> 2.6.20-1.2933.fc6
> ```
>
> Once downloaded, the packages may be installed with the rpm command
>
> ```
> # rpm -U openafs-* openafs-client-* openafs-server-* openafs-krb5-* kmod-openafs-*
> ```

For me, `uname -r` produces: `4.8.14-200.fc24.x86_64`

I don't understand where I am supposed to obtain these rpm packages from. And so I am now totally stuck again.

Answer (score 2):

> RPMs are available from the OpenAFS web site

But as I see, there are no RPMs on [their site](http://openafs.org/release/latest.html) (only SRPM). You can also rebuild them on your own:

```
wget http://openafs.org/dl/openafs/1.6.20.1/openafs-1.6.20.1-1.src.rpm
rpmbuild --rebuild openafs-1.6.20.1-1.src.rpm
```

you will need to download dependencies, but then you will get the RPMS in `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/*`.

But ... you should be good with doing

> `dnf install openafs openafs-server openafs-client openafs-krb5 kmod-openafs`

because in this case, `dnf` will download the RPM packages and install them for you (from the `copr` repository, you already enabled).

Comment: Okay, so I already have the RPMs then? Can you give me some hints on what to do next? I'm reading subsequent sections of the install guide but I just don't quite understand it. I have created the file `/usr/vice/etc/CellServDB`

Comment: It is not clear what does not work for you nor what are you trying to achieve. The installation should be complete. The other parts are configuration which widely depends on your use case.

Comment: I've tried to start the service and I see this error : `modprobe: FATAL: Module openafs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.14-200.fc24.x86_64`

Comment: I'm not sure what to do to get the right module in that directory, however.